# cassandra secondary key in trigger

Tags: cassandra

How to get Cassandra Secondary Key (time) in Java Trigger in version 3.

I can get the primary key by

```
message.put("primary_key_id", partition.metadata().getKeyValidator().getString(partition.partitionKey().getKey()));
```

Comment: https://github.com/amritsinghbains/cassandra-trigger/blob/master/CassandraPlus.java

Answer (score 0):

Running on cqlsh `DESCRIBE TABLE <keyspace>.<table>` (replace with your keyspace and table name) will give you all the information, including primary and secondary indexes

Comment: I am talking about TRIGGER not CQL